# Marker Clusterer doesn't work - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I have a very simple example for marker clustering, and it doesn't work (I already assessed many posts in the forum).
My problem is that the 13 markers are on the map, but no way to cluster them.

Here under you'll find my javascript code. I followed this example:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html

In my HTML, I included both markerclusterer.js and markerclusterer_compiled.js

Thank you in advance

---

function initialize() {

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(-39.431441,-71.286622);
map.setCenter(pos);

var all = [
    [" -41.8675 ", " -73.827697"],
    [" -23.65 ", " -70.4"],
    [" -42.48014 ", " -73.762414"],
    [" -20.2167 ", " -70.142223"],
    [" -29.906301 ", " -71.250204"],
    [" -39.272254 ", " -71.977629"],
    [" -41.3167 ", " -72.9833"],
    [" -22.908707 ", " -68.199716"],
    [" -33.4625266 ", " -70.6512506"],
    [" -39.819586 ", " -73.24521"],
    [" -33.045646 ", " -71.620361"],
    [" -33.024527 ", " -71.55234"],
    [" -43.1216233 ", " -74.0300122"],
];

for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        var lat = all[i][0];
        var lng = all[i][1];
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: latLng,});
        all.push(marker);
}

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, all);
```

};

Comment: `In my HTML, I included both markerclusterer.js and markerclusterer_compiled.js` - why both?  You only need to include that once.

Comment: Ok, I keep only markerclusterer.js, but it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markercluster takes an array of google.maps.Marker objects, the "all" array is an array of numbers onto the end of which you push some google.maps.Markers.

```
function initialize() {


var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(-39.431441,-71.286622);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: pos,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

map.setCenter(pos);

var all = [
    [-41.8675, -73.827697],
    [-23.65, -70.4],
    [-42.48014, -73.762414],
    [-20.2167, -70.142223],
    [-29.906301, -71.250204],
    [-39.272254, -71.977629],
    [-41.3167, -72.9833],
    [-22.908707, -68.199716],
    [-33.4625266, -70.6512506],
    [-39.819586, -73.24521],
    [-33.045646, -71.620361],
    [-33.024527, -71.55234],
    [-43.1216233, -74.0300122]
];

var gmarkers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        var lat = all[i][0];
        var lng = all[i][1];
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: latLng,});
        gmarkers.push(marker);
}

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);

};
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_MarkerClusterer_noWrk.html)

Comment: Ok, that's clear, thank you very much. I'm going to insert it in the main code and see if the whole thing is working :)